# Reading XML in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a field in a table in Oracle that contains an XML formatted string.  In this string is a node value that I need.  How can I parse an XML string contained in a database column/field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two options either pre-shred the xml on the db side or use an xml datasource
in SSRS.

The tricky part is to setup up the data source as embedded xml and have the value come from an ssrs expression which uses the xml column from the db as the embedded data, plus adds the query syntax. this can be done using string concatenation in the expression

Here is an article that shows the syntax: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345251.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Jason....I'll take a peak.  I am using Oracle as the backend and have noticed limitations in the Query/Expression syntax.  Might there be similar issue with the XML?

Comment: should't be the xml dataset query runs completely within ssrs